# If a basement concrete wall is 43 inches tall, is it possible to put in an egress window?

Tags: basement, windows, basement-refinishing, egress

My understanding is that the opening of the window must be 44 inches from the floor or lower.  Will it possible to put in a window and meet this requirement without cutting any concrete?  Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking whether a window is available with less than a 1" jamb?

Comment: Also... are you asking so that you can call a room in the basement a bedroom? If so, and it classifies as a bedroom, your taxes go up. I'm not suggesting you do something unsafe to avoid tax, just curious if you're doing something that requires it (or you desire it). Also, if you are not installing in concrete, are you planning to cut the sil plate, joists (band)? There would be load bearing considerations.

Comment: Yes, I plan to finish the basement so I'm interested in an extra bedroom. Interesting consideration about the taxes. I had never actually thought of that before!  I would not be cutting the sil plate or joists.  There is about 5 feet of framing above the concrete wall so I would just be cutting that.  Any load bearing concerns there?

Comment: This may be a workaround the tax issue.  We would put the bedroom window in, but not a closet.  Then if we ever sold the house, we would put the closet in before putting it on the market.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can install a code approved "egress opening"...but remember 1) sill from finish floor is 44", but you can raise the floor finish to accommodate the window frame, trim, etc., 2) overall opening must be 5.7 square feet (or 5.0 square feet if window is at grade), 3) minimum width must be 20", 4) minimum height must be 25", and 5) if a window well is required, it must be 9 square feet in area and project a minimum of 3' out. If the window well is more than 44" deep, then a ladder must be provided to the top. (See ICC R-310.1 - 310.2)